# Better way to do drill-down selection in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

I show a UIPickerView with a list of options:

- Vegetables,
- Fruits,
- Greetings,
- Shopping

When selecting any of the above options, will show another UIPickerView with options like (if we have selected greetings):

- Hi,
- Hello,
- Good morning.

When selecting any of that, will show another picker with options like:

- Hi dear,
- Hi, how are you,
- Hi, how are you doing

Now when selecting any of that, needs to be placed on a text view. The functionality is supposed to behave like templates to choose from.

I feel there is something odd in this, but cannot pinpoint it. Is there a better pattern?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of pickers, you should probably use **table views** with **disclosure indicators** (>), as seen in the Settings app. Per the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/ContentViews.html):

> The plain table style is well-suited
>   to display a hierarchy of information. Each list item can lead to a
>   different subset of information displayed in another list. Users
>   follow a path through the hierarchy by selecting one item in each
>   successive list. The disclosure indicator tells users that tapping
>   anywhere in the row reveals the subset of information in a new list.

Comment: the link goes to 404 page:-( but a good idea I appreciated